# Spring - REST - child gets inserted using @RestController but not with @RepositoryRestResource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

I currently face the problem that if I try to create a location with an address via the **RepositoryRestController, only the location gets inserted into the DB(MySQL), not the address.**

The content of the POST-request

```
 {
  "name": "locationname",
  "description": "testdescr",
  "address": {
    "city": "somecity",
    ....
  }
}
```

If I POST the exact same location to my **RestController** (api/controller/locations), **both** the address and the location are being inserted to the db (which is what I want)

***So my question is: is there a way to map the address-location relation so that both get created when I POST a location to my RepositoryRestController? (and also can be updated/deleted similarly)***

**I do NOT want to have a reference to the location in my Address.java (the address should be useable in many different classes)**

The Address should be updateable on its own.

...

The relevant classes:

Address.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "twm_address")
public class Address implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version", nullable = true)
    private int version;

    private String city;

    ...
}
```

Location.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "twm_location")
public class Location implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version", nullable = true)
    private int version;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="address_id")
    private Address address;
}
```

LocationRepository.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, String> {
}
```

AddressRepository.java

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, String> {
}
```

LocationController.java

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
@RequestMapping("api/controller/locations")
public class LocationController {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LocationController.class);

    @Autowired
    private LocationRepository locationRepo;

    @PostMapping
  Location createLocation(@RequestBody Location location) {
    return locationRepo.save(location);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need bidirectional mapping, so add `onetoone` to the Address class also, and add `mappedBy` to the one that you don't want the corresponding field to appear in the database  in.

Comment: I've added `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "address") private Location location;` to my Address class but still, only the Location gets created. ( I want an `address_id` column in my `location` table but no `location_id` in my `address` table)